"PySpark saveAsTextFile Error: HADOOP_HOME and JAVA_HOME Not Set Correctly on Windows"
Hi I was following pyspark tutorial on youtube by Coder2j The video. Im following step-by-step, at first i got an error when doing RDD Operations for Action and Transformation. I overcame the problem by initialize the os.environ that suitable for my spark version which is spark 3.5.1.
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = r'C:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Spark'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS'] = 'notebook'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = r"C:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = r"C:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
        .appName("RDD-Spark-Demo")\
        .getOrCreate()


Below is a simple structured data and i store it in rdd2 variable.
data = [('Alice', 25), ('Bob', 30), ('Charlie', 35), ('Alice', 40)]

rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

print(rdd2.collect())

But when I try to run the below code
rdd2.saveAsTextFile("output.txt")

I got this error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 6
      4 if os.path.exists(output_path):
      5     os.remove(output_path)  # Delete the file if it exists
----> 6 rdd2.saveAsTextFile(output_path)

File c:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:3425, in RDD.saveAsTextFile(self, path, compressionCodecClass)
   3423     keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path, compressionCodec)
   3424 else:
-> 3425     keyed._jrdd.map(self.ctx._jvm.BytesToString()).saveAsTextFile(path)

File c:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o411.saveAsTextFile.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:735)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getSetPermissionCommand(Shell.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:978)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:700)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:699)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.setupJob(OutputCommitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1089)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1062)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1027)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$3(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1009)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1008)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$2(PairRDDFunctions.scala:965)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:963)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$2(RDD.scala:1623)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1623)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1(RDD.scala:1609)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1609)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:564)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile$(JavaRDDLike.scala:563)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.saveAsTextFile(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.fileNotFoundException(Shell.java:547)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getHadoopHomeDir(Shell.java:568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBin(Shell.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:688)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDurationHelper(Configuration.java:1907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1867)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Configuration.java:1840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.getShutdownTimeout(ShutdownHookManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$HookEntry.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkFileUtils.createTempDir(SparkFileUtils.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkFileUtils.createTempDir$(SparkFileUtils.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:964)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHomeInner(Shell.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:515)
    ... 25 more

I pasted the error in chatgpt and it says that it cause by HADOOP_HOME is not set.
So I watched youtube video and downloaded hadoop and configured it xml files like the video.
After im done watching it and follow step-by-step and ran `hdfs namenode -format' to see if it works but nope.
C:\Users\zulki>hdfs namenode -format
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\Users\zulki\AppData\Local\Programs\Hadoop\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'The JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set' in question
@rem The java implementation to use.  Required.
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

@rem The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes.
@rem set JSVC_HOME=%JSVC_HOME%

At this point i feel like smashing my laptop, lmao.
The purpose of me learning spark, is because I have a python extraction script.The scripts have a 2 hours runtime originallly. Since it is taking so long, I added concurrent.features module and reduce the runtime to 17 minutes. But then I want to put it in AWS Lambda which has a limitation of 15 minutes timeout. So i thought if I use PySpark, it will complete below 15 minutes (I hope). I just wanna test it out.

You don't need to actually run HDFS. You just need an environment variable for Spark to know where the Hadoop packages exist. Spark might not run faster in Lambda... You could try Dask or Pandas as a starting point

I assumed Hadoop packages is where we extract our downloaded Hadoop packages to C: and initialize the HADOOP_HOME to C:\Hadoop in the code. @OneCricketeer

That's correct. However, JAVA_HOME cannot contain any spaces in the file path. That's why that's set incorrectly

OMG how did I miss that T T. I need some sleep. Thanks @OneCricketeer
